# Apache OFBiz as portal solution?

Tags: apache, portal, ofbiz

We currently need a portal solution. One of our service providers has already suggested that we develop the portal in Apache OFBiz.

Now I would like to know if Apache OFBiz is still state of the art or if it is already on the way down.

Or is there another technology we should consider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apache OFBiz is a solid Open Source framework that is actively maintained and updated by its community that is part of the Apache Software Foundation.

While the OFBiz architecture has been outlined years ago, it is still a modern framework that incorporates several pragmatic patterns and is designed to be flexible and extendable. Moreover various components and technologies have been kept up to date or replaced with newer ones over the years.

It is impossible to tell you if OFBiz is a good fit for your portal solution because I don't know your specific needs but my recommendation is to at least consider it especially if in your portal you will publish content related to products or other business entities: if this is the case then the OFBiz universal data model will be a valuable resource that will help you to achieve your goals efficiently and with high quality.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Above all, we want to use the portal to integrate existing systems.
First simply show, for example about a jump or iframe.
Later on a headless approach. Means about web services and the presentation in the portal.

Is this your opinion "easy" to implement and maintain in OFBiz.

Comment: You are most welcome. Yes, you can easily publish existing services and define/implement new ones in OFBiz and call them from external systems with various mechanisms (e.g. with JSON messages over https etc...) using the OFBiz Service Engine.

Comment: Let me add that you have a lot of different possible approaches to integrate existing systems into OFBiz: Web Services (SOAP, REST), Java Messaging (JMS), data file interfaces with different formats, and of course everything possible with HTML like linked Url's and iframe integration.

OFBiz offers a great set of different approaches and, being fully Open Source, you can add whatever interface you need without any restriction.